# How would you describe a mnemonic that works against you?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a mnemonic recently and realised that a lot of the suggestions I came across were actually making me remember the term *incorrectly*.

As a simple example, if someone asked for a mnemonic to remember "which ones are stalagmites and which ones are stalactites?", I could say:

> A stalagmite **might** fall on your head.

It might be easy to remember, like a mnemonic should be, but it's actively 'helping' you to remember incorrect information (because stalagmites can't fail on your head as they are on the ground going upwards).

We could just call this a "bad" mnemonic, but that's not very descriptive — it sounds like the mnemonic itself isn't memorable, as opposed to being easy to remember but wrong.

Searching around, I found [antimnemonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antimnemonic) as an antonym, but that's related to trying to make something hard to remember (e.g. a password).

So is there a term I could use to describe something like this? Something similar to the concept of *[false friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)* from language learning.

Happy for modifiers/adjectives of mnemoic or single word alternatives (including neologisms that are understandable on first hearing.)

As a sample sentence:

> I wouldn't use that to remember as it's a ______ mnemonic.

Comment: Uh, what's a "mnenomic"?

Comment: I don't understand the question. A stala**g**mite is on the **g**round. It's a stala**c**tite that is on the **c**eiling, so it's simply wrong information, rather than a misunderstood but correct mnemonic.

Comment: @WeatherVane but that's the point of the question, it's what to call a "mnemonic" that actually helps you to remember something incorrectly.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe I should've asked for a mnemonic for how to spell mnemonic, eh? Thanks, fixed now.

Comment: That would be *Mnemosyne*.

Comment: The question assumes a false premise. It is a mnemonic no matter what. It's helping you remember. Whether what you're remembering is *factual* is something different. You can have true memories and you can have false memories. A mnemonic simply helps you remember *something*. Assuming it's something true is just that—an assumption. I could easily have a mnemonic for remembering an example of a false statement. *A stalagmite might fall on your head* is simply an unhelpful mnemonic; but it's a mnemonic nonetheless.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica I don't think the question overall _is_ assuming a false premise, just looking for a word to describe that type of mnemonic in the same way that "false memory" describes the specific types of memories that aren't true. Agree though that the sample sentence could make that clearer, which may have added confusion!

Comment: @anotherdave A false memory is still a memory. A mnemonic that helps you remember something that isn't true is still a mnemonic.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica All false memories are still memories, but not all memories are false memories so 'false' is a useful modifier here that concisely gets across the meaning. The question was around a similarly concise adjective I could use for mnemonics in this case. Though doesn't have to be an adjective (e.g. drawing a parallel with false friend). Wasn't trying to lay any stress on it being really a mnemonics or not; have updated the sample sentence now to try and clarify what I meant.

Comment: @anotherdave So, you want something that says it's a *not very useful* mnemonic? (The accepted answer doesn't actually convey that. In fact, mnemonics, if they're *memorable*, actually *are* intuitive. *A stalagmite might fall on your head* is completely intuitive, the opposite of the answer, but just not very *useful* as a source of valid knowledge.)

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a common enough phenomenon to have thus far led to anyone coining a pithy term for it. If you're casting about for *suggestions* on what to call it, this isn't really the right place IMO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd call these [**counterintuitive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterintuitive).

They're counterintuitive because they defy your expectations as in:

> Be careful. It's counterintuitive, but the name is not a mnemonic.

---

If you want a neologism:

**Countermnemonic**: the state of the obvious mnemonic giving the wrong information.

Comment: IMO, counterintuitive sounds right for the examples, but I'd think a counterintuitive mnemonic "sounds like it's wrong, but it's actually right" rather than vice versa. Countermnemonic is a good suggestion — looking "in the wild", [here's one usage](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3865/80348c7582b0e7bf12da34126887252f291d.pdf) in a paper on semantics  that uses it similarly— 'counterintuitive, if not entirely countermnemonic'.